# regex - word matching and special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to match one word which is not surrounded by any `letter`, `number`, `special character` etc. Example of what I want:

Word is: `Hello`

Regex example I using :  `/\bHello\b/i`

PHP code where I want to use that regex :

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bHello\b/i',"some img url",$text);
```

Result :

```
hello    # match          *(that's ok)*

hellos   # no match       *(that's ok)*

hello3   # no match       *(that's ok)*

1hello   # no match       *(that's ok)*

shello   # no match       *(that's ok)*

$hello#  # match          *(that's not ok. I don't want matching!)*

hello#   # match          *(that's not ok. I don't want matching!)*
```

---

I want to match only if word isn't surrounded by any other `letter`, `number` or `SPECIAL CHARACTER`.

Word boundary is ok for letters and numbers but WordB doesnt apply for special characters and I want something like WordB. that apply for special characters too...

---

I tried this `"/(^|\s)Hello($|\s)/i"` but that's not it..

Comment: *I want to match only if word isn't surrounded by any other letter,number or SPECIAL CHARACTER* and *but WordB doesnt apply* contradict each other, don't they?

Comment: aha tnx.so how i can get what I want?

Comment: no *letter, number, special character* so you don't want anything but "hello" ?

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~(?<![\w\p{S}\p{P}])hello(?![\w\p{P}\p{S}])~i', "something", $text)`, or maybe yes, soemthing like you did but with lookarounds - `"/(?<=^|\s)Hello(?=$|\s)/i"`

Comment: So you mean [**`/(?<!\S)hello(?!\S)/i`**](https://regex101.com/r/dO1hA8/1) ?

Comment: Do you consider space as *special character* ?

Comment: (\n|\r|\t|^| )hello(\n|\r|\t|$| )

Comment: @simon PA  ,yes,only "Hello".Space is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
/(?<!\S)hello(?!\S)/i
```

PHP:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)hello(?!\S)/i', "some img url", $text);
```

You should check if next or previous character is not a non-space character. Word boundaries only apply on boundaries other than `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` characters (or any word character in any language)

Comment: Thanks!This works fine. One question.If I want to allow space around word,for example : " Hello "  or " Hello" ?

Comment: This regex will match all `hello` words with trailing or leading spaces as well. No problem.

Comment: Great.One problem appeared.There is no match if I write "Hello" without space behind.If I write like this : "Hello " then it match...

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Check demo https://3v4l.org/cOcY6

Answer (score 0):

> no letter, number, special character

If that means nothing but "hello" then use:

```
/^hello$/gi
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZ4eI3/1)

Comment: tried this but didnt work :/ Thanks anyway

Comment: because you wanted spaces as well. I assumed you didn't want it, but apparently u needed it.